# Text flows out of navigation bar, even when using word-wrap or word-break

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I'm currently making my website responsive, but this means that i also need to make the navigational bar move with the screen when you resize it, i'm trying to get css to go to the next line when i resize the browser

```css
* {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

html {
 
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

#head {
 margin-top: .5%;
 width: 87%;
 margin-left: 6.5%;
 height: 120px;
 background-color: rgb(241, 181, 0);
}

#head img {
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 width: 140px;
 height: 90px;
}

#head h3 {
 font-size: 36px;
 margin-top: -4%;
 margin-left: 45%;

}

#head p {
 margin-left: 47.4%;
 font-size: 18px;

}

#nav {
 overflow: initial;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 width: 87%;
 margin-left: 6.5%;
 background-color: rgb(187, 187, 187);
 float: left;
}

#nav ul {
 word-wrap: break-word;
 display: flex;
}

#nav li {
 padding-left: 45px;
 padding-right: 45px;
 list-style: none;
 
}
#nav a:hover {
 background-color: rgb(205, 205, 205);
}

#nav a {
 width: 1440px;
 margin-left: 1em;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 1.8em;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#nav-right {
 margin-left: 25%;
 float: right;
}

#content {
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: visible;
 background-color: rgb(241, 181, 0);
 width: 87%;
 height: auto;
 margin-left: 6.5%;

}

#gallery {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 2%;
 margin-left: 15%;
 width: 69%;
 height: 335px;
 background-color: #131313;
}

#gallery img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.galleryBTN {
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -21.4%;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgb(187, 187, 187);
 width: 6%;
 margin-left: 94%;
 height: 150px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.galleryBTN ~ .galleryBTN {
 margin-left: 0%;
}

.galleryBTN p {
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-top: 65px;
}

#webInfo {
 min-height: 400px;
 background-color: rgb(218, 166, 7);
 float: left;
 margin-top: 5%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 width: 50%;
 height: auto;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

#webInfo p {
 font-size: 18px;
 margin-left: 1%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#addr {
 min-height: 400px;
 background-color: rgb(218, 166, 7);
 overflow: hidden;
 float: right;
 margin-top: 5%;
 margin-right: 2%;
 width: 40%;
 height: auto;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

#addr img {
 width: 340px;
 height: 320px;
 margin-top: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
 float: right;
}

#addr p {
 font-size: 32px;
 text-align: right;
 margin-right: 12px;
 margin-top: 20%;
 float: right;
 margin-left: 4px;
 font-size: 16;
}

#separator {
 margin-top: 625px;
 background-color: #000;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}

#sep {
 background-color: #000;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}

.partner {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 2%;
 margin-left: 5.4%;
 margin-right: 3%;
 width: 180px;
 height: 210px;
}

.partner img {
 width: 180px;
 height: 180px;
}

.partner p {
 margin-top: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

.prices {
 overflow: hidden;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: rgb(218, 166, 7);
 margin-top: 3%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 width: 42%;
 height: 125px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

#visblock {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
}

.prices img {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 2%;
 margin-left: 2%;
 width: 90px;
}

.prices p {
 word-wrap: break-word;
 white-space: initial;
 clear: both;
 margin-left: 18%;
}

#shop {
 margin-top: 2%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 background-color: rgb(218, 166, 7);
 width: 90%;
 min-height: 960px;
 height: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

#shoppingCart {
 margin-top: 30px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 87%;
}

#shoppingCart img {
 float: right;
 width: 55px;
 height: 55px;
}

#shoppingCart p {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

.shopItem {
 overflow: auto;
 display: inline-block;
   background-color: rgb(218, 166, 7);
   margin-top: 3%;
   margin-left: 2.5%;
   margin-right: 2.5%;
  width: 27%;
  min-height: 225px;
  height: 25%;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

.shopItem img {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 3%;
 margin-top: 3%;
 width: 120px;
 height: 140px;
}

.shopItem p {
 word-wrap: break-word;
 white-space: initial;
 clear: both;
 margin-left: 7px;
 padding-bottom: 2%;

}

#shopTextContainer {
 font-size: 18px;
 height: 82%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.shopItem a {
 background-color: #FFF;
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-top: 1.2%;
 padding: 7px;
 margin-right: 36%;
 float: right;
}

#tableContainer {
 background-color: rgb(218, 166, 7);
 width: 95%;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 95%;
 margin-top: 2.5%;
 margin-left: 2.5%;
 margin-bottom: 2.5%;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

 #agendaTable table, th, td {
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;

 font-size: 32px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 100%;
}

.team {
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-left: 10%;
 margin-top: 4%;
 width: 20%;
 height: 65%;
 margin-bottom: 4%;
 
}

.team img {
 margin-top: 10%;
 margin-left: 15%;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
 width: 220px;
}

.team p {
 text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#vactitle {
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 24px; 
}

#vacature {
 width: 90%;
 height: auto;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
 
}

#vacature p {
 margin-top: 4%;
 margin-left: 10%;
}

#piste-text {
 width: 90%;
 margin-top: -150px;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 min-height: 200px;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 white-space: initial;
 overflow: hidden;

}

#pistes {
 width: 80%;
 height: 70%;
}

#pistes img {
 background-color: #000;
 width: 80%;
 height: 60%;
 margin-top: 3%;
 margin-left: 20%;
}

#form {
 text-align: center;
 background-color:  rgb(218, 166, 7);
 margin-top: 5%;
 margin-bottom: 5%;
 margin-left: 10%;
 width: 80%;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

#form input {
 min-height: 40px;
}

#form input[type=submit] {
 min-width: 240px;
}

#form input[type=text], input[type=password], select {
 min-width: 450px;
}

#form input[type=text], input[type=password], select {
 width: 60%;
 height: 6%;
 font-size: 2em;
}

#form input[type=submit] {
 margin-top: 5%;
 margin-bottom: 3%;
 width: 20%;
 height: 7%;
 font-size: 2em;
}

#form p {
 font-size: 1.8em;
 margin-top: 3%;
}

#form a {
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-top: 5%;
 font-size: 2em;
}

#form .small-form select, #form .small-form input {
 min-width: 200px;
 width: 20%;
}

#form .small-form p {
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
 display: inline-block;
}

#pageNumber {
 margin-top: 2%;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 font-size: 23px;
}

footer {
 margin-top: 5px; 
 background-color: rgb(187, 187, 187);
 text-align: center;
 width: 87%;
 font-size: 26px;
 margin-left: 6.5%;
 margin-bottom: .5%; 
 height: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 1666px) {

 #nav { 
  height: 10%;
 }

 #nav a {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: initial;
 }

 .galleryBTN {
  margin-top: -25%;
 }

  #shoppingCart {
   margin-left: 80%;
   padding: 0px;
  }

 #shoppingCart img {
  float: left;
 }

 #shoppingCart p {
  float: left;
 }

 .shopItem {
  width: 90%;
 }

 .shopItem a {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 1520px) {
 .galleryBTN {
  margin-top: -27%;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 1480px) {
 .galleryBTN {
  margin-top: -28%;
 }

 #addr p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-right: 35%;
  text-align: center;
 }

}

@media (max-width: 1400px) {
 .galleryBTN {
  margin-top: -30%;
 }

 #addr img {
  margin-right: 13%;
 }

 #addr p {
  margin-left: 15%;
 }

 #webInfo p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 1250px) {

 #separator {
  margin-top: 1050px;
 }

 #webInfo {
  width: 90%;
 }

 #addr {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  float: left;
 }
 #addr img {
  padding-left: 30%;
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  height: 30%;
 }

 #addr p {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }

 #head {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
 }

 #vactitle {
  margin-left: 10%;
 }

 #vacature {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }


 #gallery {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
 }

 .galleryBTN {
  margin-top: -20%;
 }

 .team {

  height: auto;
  width: 90%;
 }

 #pageNumber {
  font-size: 1.5em
 }

 .team img {
  margin-left: 24%;
 }

 #vacature {
  font-size: 1.4em;
 }

 .team p {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -22%;
  margin-right: 7%;
 }

 #pistes {
  width: 100%;
 }

 #pistes img {
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
 }

 #piste-text {
  font-size: 1.4em;
 }

 #head h3 {
  margin-top: -10%;
 }

 #nav {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
 }

 #content {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
 }

 .partner {
  padding-left: 15%;
 }
 #addr p {
  margin-top: 8%;
  margin-left: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
 }

 footer {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 1152px) {

 #pageNumber {
  font-size: 1.8em
 }

 .galleryBTN {
  margin-top: -23%;
 }

 #form input {
  min-width: 0px;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 952px) {

 #shoppingCart {
  margin-left: 75%;
  padding: 0px;
 }

}

@media (max-width:  906px) {

 .prices {
  width: 90%;
 }
 .galleryBTN {
  margin-top: -28%;
 }

}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
 .galleryBTN {
  margin-top: -33%;
 }

 #pageNumber {
  font-size: 1.8em
 }

 #shoppingCart {
  margin-left: 70%;
  padding: 0px;
 }

 #webInfo {
  float: left;
 }

 .partner {
  padding-left: 30%;
 }

}

@media (max-width: 631px) {

 #vacature p {
  font-size: 1.4em;
 }

 .galleryBTN {
  margin-top: -40%;
 } 
 #shoppingCart {
  margin-left: 65%;
  padding: 0px;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 524px) {
 .galleryBTN {
  margin-top: -50%;
 }

 #separator {
  margin-top: 1100px;
 }

 #form input[type=submit] {
  width: 60%;
 }

 #shoppingCart {
  margin-left: 55%;
  padding: 0px;
 }

}

@media(max-width: 480px) {

 #head h3 {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: -50%;
 }

 #head img {
  margin-left: 0px;
 }

 .galleryBTN {
  margin-top: -60%;
 }

 #separator {
  margin-top: 1200px;
 }

 #shoppingCart {
  margin-left: 50%;
  padding: 0px;
 }

 .partner {
  padding-left: 20%;
 }
} 

@media(max-width:  346px) {
 .galleryBTN {
  margin-top: -75%;
 }

 #separator {
  margin-top: 1300px;
 }

 .partner {
  padding-left: 15%;
 }
}

@media(max-width: 300px) {
 .partner {
  padding-left: 15%;
 }
}

}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title> Bigfoot bar - home </title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="img/logo.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="container">
  <div id="head">
   <img src="img/logo.png"/>
   <h3>Bigfoot bar</h3>
   <p>Een slogan hier</p> 
  </div>
  <div id="nav">
   <ul>
    <a href="index.php"> <li> Home </li> </a>
    <a href="prices.php"> <li> Prices </li> </a>
    <a href="shop.php"> <li> Shop </li> </a>
    <a href="agenda.php"> <li> Agenda </li> </a>
    <a href="team.php"> <li> Team </li> </a>
    <a href="slopes.php"> <li> Slopes </li> </a>
    <a href="login.php"><li>Login/register</li></a>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content"> 
   <div id="gallery">
    <img src="" value="0" name="img1">
     <a class="galleryBTN"><p>Next</p></a>
     <a class="galleryBTN"><p>Prev</p></a>
   </div>
  <div id="webInfo">
  <p> text about the greatness of mankind, who are we? Why are we here? Those are questions many people ask themselves, however i think the question that we all should think about is "Where will we go?". We do not know how our life will turn out to be, but we surely could predict it somehow, that is what i believe to be the truth, but there are some who do not agree with me, they think we should live in the present and not think about our future, which is silly to think about, because the offspring that we create will have to live here, meaning that our problems will become their problems in the future. I really hope that the government has some kind of plan for the people living in the country that are getting older, the newer generations won't be able to help their parents financially because the scale of support will be 2:1 in around 30 to 40 years! Yes, shocking isn't it? We as children in the netherlands will be screwed due to these plans of parents, such a SHAME!!! </p>
  </div>
  <div id="addr">
   <img src="img/adress.png">
   <p>Adress: <br>
    New York City
    <br> Lorem Ipsum
    <br> 3881TC, ergens</p>
  </div>
   <hr id="separator">
   <div class="partner">
    <img src="img/partners/img1.png">
    <p> Een partner </p>
   </div>
   <div class="partner">
    <img src="img/partners/img1.png">
    <p> Een partner </p>
   </div>
   <div class="partner">
    <img src="img/partners/img1.png">
    <p> Een partner </p>
   </div>
   <div class="partner">
    <img src="img/partners/img1.png">
    <p> Een partner </p>
   </div>
   <div class="partner">
    <img src="img/partners/img1.png">
    <p> Een partner </p>
   </div>
   <div class="partner">
    <img src="img/partners/img1.png">
    <p> Een partner </p>
   </div>
   <div class="partner">
    <img src="img/partners/img1.png">
    <p> Een partner </p>
   </div>
   <div class="partner">
    <img src="img/partners/img1.png">
    <p> Een partner </p>
   </div>
   <div class="partner">
    <img src="img/partners/img1.png">
    <p> Een partner </p>
   </div>
   <div class="partner">
    <img src="img/partners/img1.png">
    <p> Een partner </p>
   </div>

   <div id="visblock"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <footer>Een geweldig copyright bericht</footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

As you can see here if you do not put it in full view, the nav text will flow out of the navigational bar, but it should break and go under the other links of the website, this is for an assignment we have received, we need to create a responsive website, and i'm quite far right now!

I'd appreciate any help, thanks!.

Comment: The only valid child of `ul` is `li`. You can't wrap an `li` in an `a`. And you are giving your nav links a width of 1440px. That doesn't sound right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `flex-wrap: wrap;` on your container.

something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="prices.php">Prices</a></li>
        <li><a href="shop.php">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="agenda.php">Agenda</a></li>
        <li><a href="team.php">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="slopes.php">Slopes</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#nav li {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Theres a guide here on all the flex box options: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Making sites responsive is a fiddly, you may want to consider a grid system to help with this. Frameworks like Bootstrap and Foundation make use of grid systems to great effect. If you want something more lightweight you can use something like [skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/%22skeleton%22)

Comment: This simply puts every single one below the other, i'm looking for the div text to continue in the next row

Comment: You need to give each item a width and ensure they are display:inline-block. See my example above with the #nav li {width 100px}

Comment: If you don't, each item is taking up the full with and therefore forcing the next item onto the next row.

Comment: Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/u2eg9b6z/  there are lots of different configurations for flexbox, please see the link in my original answer for more details

Comment: @pandaJuan here is another example with the list items justified to the left https://jsfiddle.net/u2eg9b6z/1/